# PowerShell Web Services (Management oData IIS Extensions)?

Tags: web-services, powershell, odata

There are references to this "Loch Ness" feature across Microsoft's announcements for both PoSh3 & 4; however, I am unable to locate  *useful, current* documentation on PSWS. I even went as far as to spin up a VM and installed related roles, features, and downloadable binaries from Microsoft's referenced sites. The only content, binaries, and help that I could find is a year old and is very poorly documented. Microsoft's own MSDN pages about Management oData IIS Extensions is still incomplete. (and doesn't work on W2k12 or W2k12R2) While another section of MSDN covers the oData classes, it does not cover how to utilize the PSWS / IIS extensions with the required schema designer...etc.

All that so you know that I've done the research but am unable to find sufficient & current documentation on how to employ PSWS / Management oData IIS extensions. Does anyone know who to contact within Microsoft to get this information? Or has anyone recently used the oData / PSWS Schema Designer to create a PoSh odata service?

TIA.

-Eric

Answer (score 1):

Have a look in the url below if you haven't already. there's a doc inside the zip file.

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mgmtODataWebServ/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=5728

Comment: I'm still fishing for the doc file, but the samples now appear at https://github.com/microsoftarchive/msdn-code-gallery-microsoft/tree/master/Official%20Windows%20Platform%20Sample/Windows%208.1%20desktop%20samples/%5BC%23%5D-Windows%208.1%20desktop%20samples/Windows%20Powershell%20%20basic%20OData%20Web%20Service%20sample and Windows%20Powershell%20%20role-based%20OData%20Web%20Service%20sample/C%23

Answer (score 1):

Here's a newer link to the MSDN doc:
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh880865(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: archived page available at https://web.archive.org/web/20130113100203/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh880865(v=vs.85).aspx